# Unable to get correct answer even after fulfilling sample test cases

Tags: java

The question of the problem is given in the following link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRICECON

I have written the program and it also satisfies the sample test case but still shows wrong answer. Any sort of help would be great.

I have taken care of all test cases and I believe that my program is missing out on some corner cases.

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class sample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      String s = "";
      char ch = '\u0000';
      char ch1 = '\u0000';
      int  i =0;
      int n = 0;
      int k =0;
      int arr_ref = 0;
      int decrease = 0;
      int p[] = new int[10000];
      //int p1[] = new int[10000];
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      int test_cases = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine() );
      if(test_cases > 100 || test_cases < 1 )
      {
            System.exit(0);
      }
      for(int z = 0 ; z<test_cases ; z++)
      {
      
       s = "";
       ch = '\u0000';
       ch1 = '\u0000';
       i =0;
       n = 0;
       k =0;
       arr_ref = 0;
       decrease = 0;
      
       s = in.readLine();
       for(i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++)
       {
         if(s.charAt(i) == ' ' )
         break;
         else
         ch += s.charAt(i);
         
       }
       //System.out.println("ch : "+ch+"|");
       for(k = i+1 ; k<s.length() ; k++ )
       {
         ch1+= s.charAt(k);
       }
      n = (int)(ch)-48;
      k = (int)(ch1)-48;
      //System.out.println("n : "+n);System.out.println("k : "+k);
      if(n > 10000 || n < 1 )
      {
            System.exit(0);
      }
      if(k > 1000 || k < 1 )
      {
            System.exit(0);
      }
      
      s = in.readLine();
      /*for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
      {
       p[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine() );
       if(p[i] > k)
       decrease += p[i] - k;
      }*/
      arr_ref = 0;
      for(i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++ )
      {
          p[i]= 0;
          
      }
      
      /*for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
      {
          System.out.println("p["+(i+1)+"] : "+p[i]);
          
      }*/
      for( i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++)
      {
        
        if(s.charAt(i) == ' ')
        arr_ref++;
        else
        p[arr_ref] = (p[arr_ref]*10)+((int)(s.charAt(i))-48); 
        
      }
      
      for( i = 0 ; i <= arr_ref ; i++)
      {
       //System.out.println("p["+(i+1)+"] : "+p[i]);
       if(p[i] > 1000 || p[i] < 1)
       {
           System.exit(0);
       }
       if(p[i] > k)
       {
           decrease += p[i] - k;
       }
      }
      System.out.println(decrease);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like more of a homework question. Try breaking down the problem into its simplest case and build up from there (N = 1). Most likely you are running into issues when trying to convert strings to integers. You're making it way harder on yourself than necessary. There are built-in methods to reach integers from standard input. https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/java-program-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input/

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work when inputs are given like this

3

5

4

10

2

3

4

5

But works for

3

5 4

10 2 3 4 5

I suggest you to use java.util.Scanner class which will work for both formats..
Other than that, Your logic is correct.
A sample solution for your reference is mentioned.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Store each answer in array and print at the end.

Comment: I did try out your recommendation but still, it is showing wrong answer. Please help @Arjun